# LINQ query to use right key for the correct keyvaluepair

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list attributes, which are defined as such

```
class Attribute 
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public KeyValuePair<string, object>
}
```

and list of keys stored in a `IList<string> listOfKeys`

I would like to store all the values in a list of objects, but how do I using a linq query parse the right key, and extract the value and store them to a `list<object>`

What I have tried so far i something like

```
List<attribute> attributes;

some init stuff 

attributes.Where(x => x.Key).
```

how do use my keys here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use combination of `Any`:

```
IList<string> listOfKeys = new List<string>();
var attributes =  new List<Attribute>();            
attributes.Where(a => listOfKeys.Any(l => a.Foo.Key == l));
```

And `Attribute` class:

```
class Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public KeyValuePair<string, object>  Foo { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want get `IEnumerable<object>`:

```
var result = attributes.Where(a => listOfKeys.Any(l => a.Foo.Key == l))
    .Select(s => s.Foo.Value);
```

Comment: this though returns `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` Where I want a `IEnumerable<object>`